# HTTPwebrequest image click post

Tags: post, httpwebrequest, scrape

So I am trying to navigate http://www.historicflyingclothing.com/shop.php by first clicking on an item in the dropdown. After posting the value from the dropdown using :

```
string poststring = String.Format("Cat1={0}", "7");
CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.historicflyingclothing.com/shop.php");

httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
httpRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
httpRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(poststring);
httpRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
requestStream.Close();


HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

I was able to get the items on the page.
The problem is when I need to click on the next button. I was hoping to use the `CookieContainer` to help me navigate but I cant figure out what the post data should be. The html code for the next click is:

```
<form method="POST" class="shopform" action="shop.php"> 
    <p style="text-align: center"> <input type="IMAGE" name="Submitnext" src="buttons/next.gif" value="npage" style="margin-bottom: -4pt"></p>
</form>
```

With the drop down the name was "Cat1" and value was "7" but what do I use for this IMAGE?

Comment: I've edited your formatting as your HTML was invisible which probably prevented you from getting an answer sooner. In the future you may want to ensure your question is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you've provided and listed on that website, the values you need to post are:

Submitnext=npage

You'll noticed the name you're posting is contained in the "name" attribute and the value is contained in the "value" attribute.